# Classifying with books vs taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I have a tree of research topics, such as Mathematics/Algebra/*subtopics*.

The users should not be able to edit too broad topics such as Algebra, but have the permissions for smaller subtopics.

Should I do it as one big Book or as several books classified by taxonomy (which takes only broad terms such as Algebra), with smaller subtopics implemented as book pages?

Comment: A related question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7217/book-module-versus-taxonomy-module - note that it is NOT a duplicate question, my question is more specific

Comment: I think also updating to D8 would matter.